# Why is the program crashing?

Tags: c++, crash

I am making a c++ program which should read in from standard input an integer N. It should then read from a file "data.txt" values into an array of size N. then it should pass it to a function which reverses the array and returns a pointer to the new array. Then it should print the contents of the returned pointer's array. But everytime I run the program it crashes. Any ideas?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int * reverseArray(int * arr, const int size)
{
//int arr1[size];
int *arr2 = new int[size];
for(int iii = 0; iii < size; iii++)
{
    (*(arr2+iii)) = (*(arr + size - 1 - iii));
}

return arr2;
}

int main()
{
int N;
cin >> N;
if(N >= 0 && N <= 50)
{
    ifstream inputFile;
    inputFile.open("data.txt");
    int *arr = new int[N];
    int iii = 0;
    while(inputFile >> (*(arr+iii)) && iii < N)
    {    iii++;}

    arr = reverseArray(arr, N);

    for(int jjj = 0; jjj < N; jjj++)
    {
        cout << (*(arr+jjj)) << endl;
    }

    delete [] arr;
    inputFile.close();
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the exact error that you get?

Comment: So, where does it crash?  And if this is C++, why not use `std::vector` and `std::reverse`?  Also, you're leaking the memory you've originally allocated to `arr` (also a good reason to switch to `std::vector`).

Comment: does`data.txt` exists in the required location?

Comment: what line does it crash?

Comment: Looking at it quickly I see it clearly leaks but can't see where the crash is at present

Comment: if data.txt has fewer than N rows you'll be swapping then printing uninitialised data but that wouldn't normally cause a crash.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the problem is here:

```
while(inputFile >> (*(arr+iii)) && iii < N)
```

The check to ensure `iii` is less than `N` occurs after the access. Reorder the conditions:

```
while(iii < N && inputFile >> (*(arr+iii)) )
```

Note this line introduces a memory leak:

```
arr = reverseArray(arr, N);
```

As this is C++ consider using `std::vector<int>` instead.

Comment: wow, you guys are amazing. that was exactly the problem, I just reversed the order and I believe I got rid of the memory leak by assigning the return of the function to another pointer and deleting that one also. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest changing it to the following. Although would point out you'll get undefined output should N < number of items in data.txt.

```
while (iii < N && inputFile.good())
{
    inputFile >> *(arr+iii);
    ++iii;
}

int *arrRev = reverseArray(arr, N);

for(int jjj = 0; jjj < N; ++jjj)
{
    cout << (*(arrRev+jjj)) << endl;
}

delete [] arr;
delete [] arrRev;
inputFile.close();
```